# cannot redirect subfolders via htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a htaccess problem

all urls will redirect via access:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?load=content&url=$1
```

Domain *www.domain.de/nicepage* will redirect to *www.domain.de/index.php?load=content&url=nicepage*

Now I would like to redirect 'subfolder':

from *www.domain.de/faq/nicefaq* to *www.domain.de/index.php?load=faqdetail&url=nicefaq*

That's what I am try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?load=content&url=$1
RewriteRule ^faq/(.*)$ index.php?load=faqdetail&url=$1
```

This does not work. everytime i call the page i will redirect to load=content.

Can You help me pls?

thanks in advance and best regards
Maddin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both RewriteRules match against the same condition. As the first you wrote matches everything, the second is never reached. Just change the order:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^faq/(.*)$ index.php?load=faqdetail&url=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?load=content&url=$1
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^faq/(.*)$ index.php?load=faqdetail&url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/+faq [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?load=content&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```